# How do I remove the star nut from a fork?

Tags: fork

My old fork didn't have enough eyelets, so I bought a new one. Installation has gone well, except that I need to put the cap on the new one. The cap is held on by a bolt, which threads into a metal piece. This metal piece is firmly in the old fork. How do I take this piece out, do I just buy a new one from the store?

[image: the piece in question]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called a star nut. Buy a new one, it isn't worth saving. You can get new star nuts for $2, and the only reasonable ways to save the old one are:

- By trying to push it from the bottom of the fork steerer, for this you need a long tool, ideally something that is threaded like a long threaded rod with the correct threading -- however, the bottom of the fork steerer is usually bit smaller in inner diameter so the star nut may become too much bent if doing that, and you may need to bend it back to its original shape
- By trying to bend the parts that touch the fork with pliers, then you maybe could pull the star nut, but now you have the problem that you need to bend all of them back to the original position

If your time has any value, buy a new one.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the real name, I see that a new one is affordable.

Comment: Beware that inserting the new one isn't trivial, you need to get the alignment right. There is an insertion tool for that.

Comment: Yep, insertion tool is good to have, but a bolt and hammer and lots of carefulness can do it without the tool.

Answer (score 2):

Pushing the star nut down did not work great for me, but this did:

1. Drill through the middle of starnut to destroy it.
2. Use pliers to bend the rest and pull it up.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, find a washer bigger in diameter then forks steerer with a hole that's not too big for a bolt that fits the star nut.

Put the washer on top of steerer, with bolt going thru it, then start wrenching. When star nut reach the top, tap the washer and it will pop out.

Yes, it's the most primitive puller possible.

Comment: Star nuts are specifically designed to not let this work. I would recommend against forcing it.

Comment: Do you mean "on top" or "underneath" ?  I can see this puller working great if you could pull the star nut down through the fork, perhaps greasing the inside first to reduce scoring.  You'd have to remove the wheel and any mudguards, and any rim brake caliper to get a clear path down-and-out.  You;d need a long bolt, or more-likely some threaded rod/allthread.

Comment: Well, it will remove the star nut in either direction, if you and your bolt is persistent enough. It will scratch the steerer tube, but will work. Star nut is not a structural item. Stem bolts are the ones that keeps your fork in. The real reason to use a star nut is to preload headset bearings, remove slack and adjust steering ."hardness"

Comment: Or, you can drill into the star nut, and bang with a rod - its very effective, too. Unless you have a carbon fiber steerer, almost anything works ..